# In prometheus if a want to plot one graph that has both cpu usage memory usage in bytes for a particular namespace what query is to be written?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have written this kind of query but it doesn't work

```
namespace:container_CPU_usage:sum and namespace:container_memory_usage_bytes:sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `or` instead of `and`:

```
namespace:container_CPU_usage:sum or namespace:container_memory_usage_bytes:sum
```